# Mono and winforms control height issue

Tags: winforms, ubuntu, mono, height

I have been testing my .NET windows applications with Mono on Ubuntu and noticed that my controls are always stretched in height.  Width wise appears to be fine.  I have a stack of 5 comboboxes that fit nicely within a panel, but with Mono on Ubuntu the comboxes are too tall and the last comboxbox is pushed into the boundary of the panel.  Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Different font metrics could do this.  Does the text fit?

Comment: The text is not distorted in any way.  It fits and looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can check and see if you are using AutoScaling by accident:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_WinForms

Or someone pointed me to a really weird cause of this a couple of days ago, having Thai fonts installed on Ubuntu:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/539008

Comment: I tried disabling autoscaling and still have the same problem.